# Continuously checking for current time

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I have an array containing specific times and I want when the current time is one of those in the array to make an alert to the user (like an alarm system), I am using a timer now that checks it every 60 seconds, but is there any better way to do it, rather than a timer?

Comment: Figure out what the next alert time is (place the times in a queue of some sort) and set a timer for that time.  When the time's up dequeue the next time and set the timer again.  SOP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you use a timer (for each item in your array) that is set to fire at the desired time? instead of firing the timer every 60 seconds.
Assuming the app would be running all the time.

Comment: Another solution is to issue a Local Notification / Remote Notification (APNS) at specific time.

Comment: Yep, that is a good solution too, specially if your app may go to background and you still want the alerts.

Comment: You know what time it is (current time), you also know what time you want the timer to fire, you subtract them and set that duration for your timer (you "schedule" you timer for that time). Is that clear? if you can't get it to work just post your code and I or others can review your code.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Ali said: a better design would be to sort the array and set a timer for the soonest time. When that one fires, set a timer for the next event, and so forth. Timers don't grow on trees, y'know.

Comment: Sure, but if the number of items in the array is not large, I personally rather make a timer for each. Maybe its me but I think it's a more stable/reliable/simple design. Still you are absolutely right it is not resource efficient specially if you have many of them and you are on lower end devices.